# Whats a better way to have unique user rooms

Tags: javascript, meteor

The logic is click user, checks for existing rooms. If there is, go to existing room. If not, creates new room and goes into it. There will only be a unique room between the user and myself. When I click user for first time, it sets a unique Id for the room. But if i click the name a 2nd time, it routes me to a room with url params as user's Id.

Was wondering whats wrong and if theres a cleaner way. I also cant display the name of the receiver. I used helpers `Meteor.users.findOne({ _id: this.receiver })`.

**roomDetail**

```
    //subscription
    self.subscribe('room', Router.current().params._id);
    //.. room helper
    return Rooms.findOne({ _id: Router.current().params._id });
```

**User page to click button**

```
    Template.usersShow.events({
      'click .user': function(event) {                       
        var receiver = this._id;           

        if (receiver) {
          var res = Rooms.findOne({ 'receiver' : receiver }); 
          if(res){     
              //..route to the existing room
          } else {
              //...create new room
```

Comment: It is unclear what the distinction between 'receiver' and 'owner' is. Can two rooms exists where the receiver and owner are swapped? Also, can you explain how the room `_id` and `chatId`  are used, and what `_id` is expected in the 'roomDetail' route?

Comment: say u click a user's name. That user = receiver, you = owner.  For roomDetail, I need unique id that doesnt change. 2 users and 1 room, i.e from you or the user's perspective, room id is not related to any user's id. chatid is probably not meaningful ...so I think need to change the server code for `room` publish ..from chatid --> roomid. basically only one room between 2 users, no duplicates.

Comment: The title of receiver and owner is fixed into that room. So if the user responds, user is still the receiver. But im thinking from the point of the user, cos if user decides to click your name...it will find rooms where your id = receiver so ends up 2 rooms between 2 users :( There must be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to ensure that there is only one room between any pair of users you should treat both the "initiator" and the "receiver" equally. Below I describe one way of doing just that.

A room has an id (the built in `_id`) and the ids of both users:

```
{
    userA: "aaaa",
    userB: "bbbb",
    // ...
}
```

When finding a room between "aaaa" and "bbbb", we don't know which is which. We can avoid this problem by imposing the rule that **`userA` has the id that sorts before `userB`**. To make it easy to use this rule, we write a helper function:

```
function userAAndB(user1, user2) {
    if (user1 < user2) return {userA: user1, userB: user2};
    else return {userA: user2, userB: user1};
}
```

Now if we want to find *the* room for users `x` and `y`, we can find it like this:

```
var theRoom = Rooms.findOne(userAAndB(x, y));
```

The helper can also be used as a starting point for creating a new room.

In order to find all rooms that a user is in, we can use an [`$or` operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/):

```
var allRoomsWithX = Rooms.find({$or: [{userA: x}, {userB: x}]});
```

---

Using this design, there are a couple of ways that you can implement your routes and buttons:

1. Put the other user's id in the route, like `allRooms/:otherUser`. The router, template and publication can use `userAAndB(userId, otherUser)` to find the room they need.

   In this case, you need some code that creates the room if it doesn't exist. On the server is best, so you could put it in the publish function. This means that the client doesn't need to know the room id, and can simply link to the right route.
2. Put the room id in the route, like `allRooms/:_id`. The router, template and publication can use the room's `_id`.

   In this case, you need to find out what the correct room id is for a given pair of users in order to make a link. This is pretty easy using `userAAndB(userId, otherUser)`. You also need to create a new room if one doesn't exist. You could do this when the user clicks on the link.

   It might be best to make a Meteor Method to get the room id for a pair of users so that you don't need to send all of the rooms to the client. The method would be something like `getRoomId(user1, user2)` and it would create a room if needed, then return the id.

---

Slightly related, because you are asking about nicer ways to structure code, I want to mention Iron Router's `waitOn` and `data` features.

You can have Iron Router make subscriptions and fetch data for you, so that you don't need to do it in your templates. This is great if a template can't be sensibly rendered until the main data has loaded, and would probably be good in your `roomDetail` route. Look for `waitOn` and `data` in [this section of the Iron Router guide](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#route-specific-options) for an example.

Comment: @Thinkerer, I am not in the mood :) You will need to decide which of the two options, 1 or 2, is best for your app, and what that means for your template code.

Comment: Using an array of user ids sounds good too. I just learnt about the [`$all` operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/#op._S_all) which would be helpful. You could even use `$size` too and have a system that can be extended to arbitrary lists of users: `{people: {$all: [user1, user2], $size: 2}}` will find the "private" room between `user1` and `user2` while excluding any group rooms with both of them.

Comment: Ive fitted the parts in. Theres an issue, when I click the name of the user, it routes into `allRooms/userId` rather than `allRooms/roomId`. I need the latter to work, whats wrong with my lines? The problem arises when I click from the user's name, with or without existing rooms. The only time it works is when I enter from a list of rooms instead. Then it routes correctly.

Comment: @Thinkerer, you will need some code to determine the correct room I'd using the ideas here. I suspect it will look a lot like your initial click handler. Once you have the correct room I'd it's just a matter of `Router.go('roomDetail', {_id: roomId})`. If you are having trouble with some specific part of the implementation, I'd suggest posting a new question with a smaller focus.

Comment: what I meant is i have already put the code in and tested, and thats the result I got. But anyway will go with your suggestion and thanks!